# Cloudwatch rule triggering on web ui created instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function that tags instances after they are created.  I have been using the following rule to trigger this.

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "RunInstances"
    ]
  }
}
```

However this rule only triggers on api created instances and not ones created through the web ui console.  How can I create a rule that triggers when a new instance is created from any source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your scenario by doing the following:

- Created an AWS Lambda function to log the contents of the `event` passed to the function
- Created an Amazon CloudWatch Events rule to trigger the Lambda function on `RunInstances` (as you show, above)
- Launched an EC2 instance via the AWS CLI -- The Lambda function was triggered
- Launched an EC2 instance via the EC2 management console -- The Lambda function was triggered

Thus, **the Lambda function was triggered by launch an instance via the AWS CLI *and* the management console.**

The Lambda function was:

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print (event)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: It must be an issue with my lambda function then.  Thanks for the input.